# .htaccess redirect to same subfolder

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess, subdomain

My problem is the following: My company shares hosting with others, and we have the subdomain inside a "public_html" folder. I can enter the index of my page perfectly, that is in [www.principal.com/mypage](http://www.principal.com/mypage) it enters perfectly.

The problem is when I redirect to pages within my subdomain, they redirect to the 404 Not Found of the main page, that is to say [www.principal.com/mypage/new](http://www.principal.com/mypage/new) 404 Not Found page of principal.com

The main / public_html / .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The file public_html/mypage/.htaccess is

```
<FilesMatch ".(phtml|php|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The file public_html/mypage/public/.htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I must clarify that my subdomain worked perfectly until a few days ago, since March that it worked very well.

Wordpress is the main page of the domain, my page in the subdomain is with the Laravel framework.
So, I redirect from Laravel to Laravel whit

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth'],
    function(){
        Route::get('/onepage', 'HomeController@one');
        Route::get('/twopage', 'HomeController@two'); 
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just to clarify, what changed since a few days ago, when everything worked? Did you update anything? Did your provider?

Comment: Yes, the provider deleted the old .htaccess and created another with Wordpress, then my subdomain doesn't work.  You can see in http://www.metalnorsalta.com.ar/ as the principal and www.metalnorsalta.com.ar/autorizaciones/

Comment: Hello, change a line and it works the other way around, the subdomain works and the links on the main page do not work I changed: RewriteBase /autorizaciones I need auto_awesome Quizás quisiste decir: necesito que ambos funcionan 28 / 5000 Resultados de traducción I need both to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it
I changed The file public_html/mypage/.htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MYPAGE
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because the directives in the root level .htaccess are used even something might be directed to the site in the subfolder. Try something like this in public_html/.htaccess, to exclude requests sent to the subfoler:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/autorizaciones/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: http://metalnorsalta.com.ar/autorizaciones/tfc/18109

Comment: Yes it goes that way, but know Not Found
The requested URL /autorizaciones/tfc/18109 was not found on this server.

Comment: Hello, change a line and it works the other way around, the subdomain works and the links on the main page do not work
I changed: 
RewriteBase /autorizaciones
I need auto_awesome
Quizás quisiste decir: necesito que ambos funcionan
28 / 5000
Resultados de traducción
I need both to work